# Is function () { this.array = [newElem, ...array] } pure?

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-6

I want to know if the following two functions are pure functions

```
delete(movie: Movie): void {
    this.movies = this.movies.filter(m => m !== movie);}
```

```
receiveMovie($event) {
    this.movies = [$event, ...this.movies];
  }
```

I know that a pure function should not have any side effects, but it is not clear to me what a side effect is. If someone could explain it to me, I would be extremely grateful.

Comment: Those functions are not pure because they mutate the state of the class. Also the output is not determined by the input

Comment: Pure functions only operate on the arguments they receive and do not reference anything from the outer scope, they also don't modify their arguments and they return a value to communicate with the outside world

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`(m => m !== movie)` is the only pure function in your code sample.

> it is not clear to me what a side effect is

A side effect is a visible state change.

`f(x)` is pure if there does not exist any sequence of operations including a call to `f` such that swapping the call to `f` with an adjacent operation would cause a different result.

```
delete(movie: Movie): void {
    this.movies = this.movies.filter(m => m !== movie);}
```

is not pure because reordering step 2 and 3 affects the result of

```
let m = ..., aMovie = ...;
m.receiveMovie(aMovie);             // Step 1
const n = m.movies.length;          // Step 2
movies.delete(aMovie);              // Step 3
console.log(n === m.movies.length);
```

Similarly, if you were to remove step 3 altogether, reordering steps 1 and 2 affects the result, so `.receiveMovie` is not pure either.

It doesn't matter whether the result of the pure function changes when its arguments change.
Only whether the result of some other operation could change.

When determining purity it's important to ignore changes due to sources of non-determinism, like the system clock, random number generators, and promise resolution due to network delays.

Note: this definition means that anything that `throw`s is not pure.  That's arguably ok since a throw causes a non-local transfer of control, but others might find that against their intuition.  You could adjust the definition to work around that.

---

It's really hard to prove purity for non-trivial functions in JavaScript.

For example,

```
function f(x) { return x + x; }

function blowUpTheMoon() {
  console.log('pow!');  // a visible side effect
}

// Reordering has a visible effect.
console.log('start');
f({ toString: blowUpTheMoon });
```

and there's all kinds of [*Proxy*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) tricks that let you show that functions that look up a property or do an `instanceof` check are not pure.

Answer (score 0):

You're altering the `this.movies` reference, so no, this is not pure.

A side effect is something a function does besides returning a value. If the function *does* something other than calculating and returning a value based on its input, it is not pure. Ask yourself: did this function change anything outside of itself? If it does, it's not pure.

Also, if a function doesn't return a value, it is necessarily impure it isn't doing anything useful.